# Uncaught Error: Expected at most 1 argument for query(), got 2 - chrome.tabs.query()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Why I get this error `browser-polyfill.js:806 Uncaught Error: Expected at most 1 argument for query(), got 2` from the `chrome.tabs.query()` method? It's specified inside the documentation that a callback can be defined and I have this code in my `background.js` file

```
// using browser to have cross compatibility with mozilla and opera 
browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
  console.log(tabs)
})
```

Comment: The `browser` polyfill returns a Promise and hence should be used differently, not with a callback, see examples in the [documentation](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill).

Comment: Yeah, I've read later this detail, I've replaced the callback with a `then()` and now seems to work fine. Just a dumb question, I'm activating the `page_action` after checking the active tab url, I've noticed that I need to switch the tab befor that I can use the `tabs.onActivated()` and then `tabs.query()`, Is there another method that I can use?Declarative content didn't work in my case :/